# Spelling checker for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking

Is there anyway to create C# spelling checker without using Office library? I would be happy with the simplest possible solution.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253064/net-spell-check-control

Comment: The *simplest possible solution* is: `if (str.Contains("teh")) str = str.Replace("teh", "the");`. There's your spell checker and now you're happy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use NHunspell.

> [Spell Check, Th­e­saurus and Hyphen­ation: NHun­spell](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/nhunspell-net-spell-checker.aspx)

personally, i have tried it. its good.

From the NHunspell project page:

> NHunspell is based on Hunspell and
>   brings the Open Office spell checking,
>   hyphenation and thesaurus to the
>   Microsoft® .NET Framework. NHunspell
>   is a .NET (C#, VB) library and wraps
>   the native libraries Hunspell, Hyphen
>   and MyThes.
>
> The integrated libraries are used in
>   OpenOffice and work with the
>   dictionaries published on
>   OpenOffice.org.
>
> NHunspell is licenced under:
>   GPL/LGPL/MPL. Free use in commercial
>   applications is permitted according to
>   the LGPL and MPL licenses. Your
>   commercial application can link
>   against the NHunspell DLLs.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution ever is to use WPF: TextBox and RichTextBox controls of WPF support spell checking by default, just add the control, enable spell checking, and you have done!

Here is a sample code:

```
<TextBox Margin="53,86,51,97" Name="textBox1" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: I like this WPF solution a lot. It makes me want to try WPF now!

Answer (score 0):

I know of this project NetSpell. It is in sourceforge and you can find many reference that discuss it in codeproject or search on google

Dont think the project is active recently, but still pretty good for use

```
http://www.aspcode.net/Use-NetSpell-in-your-ASPNET-20-application.aspx
```