# Where can I find a free, easy to implement spellcheck component for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, spell-checking

This may be a tall order, but I'd like to find a spellchecker component that is easy to implement (I only need to spell-check one TextBox). I've looked around and cannot seem to find anything that doesn't cost a fortune, or isn't overly complicated to implement. I did find a wrapper for NHunspell, but couldn't get it to actually display the spell-check box for whatever reason.

ComponentOne's spell-check control is absolutely excellent, but of course, costs an absolute fortune since you can't buy just that component, you have to buy the whole suite. All the other ones I've found seem to be the same way.

I liked the ComponentOne version the best because all you had to do way reference it, initialize, and when you called it you simply told it which control to check. It was lovely.

Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-spellcheck-class)

Comment: @Hans - I disagree. The SpellCheck class is dependent on WPF.  I think this is a perfectly valid question that is distinct from the one to which you link.  The people answering are producing excellent answers that contribute value to the real question at hand: *free*, easy to implement spell checking components.

Comment: @Wayne - why isn't WPF a valid solution?  Its free, solid, included with any recent .NET version and usable in Winforms.  Beats buying from ComponentOne.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Spell Check control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253064/net-spell-check-control) Hans just found the wrong duplicate. This question *has* been asked before. And for what it's worth, I like NHunspell. I recommend solving the problem you have with it, rather than using an inferior alternative.

Comment: @Hans WPF *may* be a solution, but it's not the *only* one, as evidenced by the responses below.

Comment: @Cody never heard about NHunspell, i saw the site just now and its seems really the reply to this question

Comment: @Felice: Apparently the asker has heard of it: "I did find a wrapper for NHunspell, but couldn't get it to actually display the spellcheck box for whatever reason." Otherwise, I'd have posted it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check out NetSpell, very easy to implement.

Link to an example
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/netspell.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use wpf, and you can accept do some work by hand, a very insteresting component is the SharpDevelop text editor: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Using%20the%20texteditor.ashx it is not exactly a drag'drop component, but you can extend it with some sort of language service to provide your own spell check mechanism. The component offers to you all the graphic part: squiggles, highlighting and so on. And it is Winform (even if now there is a wpf version too)