# English spell Checker with synonyms c#

Tags: c#, spell-checking

Is it possible to make an English spellchecker like Microsoft Office that can also show synonyms for words from a paragraph in a textbox?

I'd like to press a button and have it identify grammatical mistakes in the text and provide synonyms for the words.

Comment: You know its possible, Microsoft did it.  Putting the team of expert linguists together to create the spell and synonym database is the tricky part.  What can you afford?

Comment: I was thinking of using microsoft word feature if possible it shows synonyms

Comment: you might want to start your project by spelling "spellchecker" correctly :-). I should also add that Word's current spellchecker isn't perfect and not all synonyms are created equal.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the information.I have seen on internet that there are article or somewhat text spinner software they implement it some how how do they do that?

Answer (score 4):

Check this, it seems quite simple

[MSDN - SpellCheck Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

following links might help you

[Walkthrough: Accessing the Spelling Checker in Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168503%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[.NET Spell Check control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253064/net-spell-check-control)

[Spell Checker](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/nhunspell-net-spell-checker.aspx)